# How to apply a css transition effect to a image without losing responsive property

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to add some effect of transition with css to some images but when it's applied the image expand to all is father container and don't show the text before it

Something like this is the html that I have:

```
<div id="people">
    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6">
        <div id="profilePic">
           <img class="img-responsive img-circle bottom" src="img/someone_old.png"> 
           <img class="img-responsive img-circle top" src="img/someone_now.png">
        </div>
        <h4>
            <strong>Someone</strong>
        </h4>
        <p>Description.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

I'm using bootstrap and this other css for making the effect of transition and as well as responsive

```
#people .img-responsive {
    margin: 0 auto
}

#profilePic img{
    position: absolute;
    left:0;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
    transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
}

#profilePic img.top:hover{
    opacity: 0; 
}
```

This effect is for making interact the mouse with the images, been one in top of the another, so when the mouse pass hover, the images interchange themself.
The thing is that isteed of only using is `div profilePic` container, they expand and use all is `father div`, covering the title and the paragraph that is below it

Comment: My bad, I make same mistakes in the example, I just correct they